# NestJS: How to handle custom directors errors

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I am having a ***NestJS*** backend application.

**my-controller.ts**

```
import { Roles } from 'private-npm';

export class myController {
    constructor(private readonly service: MyService) { }

---> @ClientRoles({ roles: ['test-role'] })
    @Get()
    @ApiOperation({ title: 'List users' })
    async listUsers(): IUser[] {
      return this.service.listUsers(); 
    }
}
```

*@ClientRoles* throws `Permission not fulfilled, 403 (FORBIDDEN)` error, If a user does not have required roles (e.g. *test-role*).

The problem is, ***I can see the error message (*ERROR: Permission not fulfilled*) in the terminal but I do not get the same error message in my Swagger UI response body***.

Instead of an error message, I get the following error message in Swagger UI.

```
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

It's pretty hard to debug also.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does the decorator through the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your guard should NOT throw an error. It should implement the CanActivate interface and have a canActivate method, which returns `boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean>` being `false` if access is denied. And you should pass it to the `@UseGuards` decorator. Read more about Guards: https://docs.nestjs.com/guards

Usually best practice is to have one Guard which reads metadata written by another decorator.. eg:

```
@Roles(['roleA', 'roleB'])
@UseGuards(new RoleGuard())
```

Although you could combine those by making a factory function for which you pass the roles and it returns the guard instance.